# core dump size 0 in kubernetes pod

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, linux-kernel

I have set my K8s Node's core_pattern to kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t. Since that was the only way I was able to get the pods to change its core_pattern.
But, now I the cores I generate using kill -6 , the core file generated is always of size 0. Same thing works in just the docker environment, but not able to get it to work in k8s pods.

I am running container on ubuntu 18.04LTS.

```
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup 0 Feb  5 02:10 /tmp/core*
```

I have tried the following:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t
```

Also:

```
echo 'root - core unlimited' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo '*    - core unlimited' >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo 'kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue
If I try the user to root, it works though